# Facets not working with Algolia search

Tags: views, 9, search

I am implementing Algolia search and using the following contributed modules

1. [Search API Algolia](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_algolia)
2. [Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets)

After configuring the modules, the content/data indexing is working fine and is reflecting on Algolia server.
For search page, I am using Drupal views of type **Index Algolia index** and search is working fine using the Full text search filter.
After configuring the Facets, the block is displaying the **Content Type** facet and showing the total count as well like

- page (12)
- blog (9)

Upon clicking these facets, the search results are not filtered.
I have configured the **Type** Facet and its display on Algolia server.
On Algolia server the facets and search is working fine and as expected but Facets not working on my Drupal site.
I am not using any specific value in **Filter key** while configuring **facet source configuration**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bug reports should be posted on the module's issue queue on drupal.org

Comment: @Hudri - I would have done that if I was 100% sure that it is a bug, but right now the issue could be due to some config mismatch which I am not sure of at this moment.